# How do I get a label in Xcode to show the day of the week (Swift/Swift 2)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

I'm an absolutely coding newb and I want to create a school planner app. I have the general nuts and bolts sorted - but I want to create a function where a label displays the day of the week, which a button would then interpret and would then send the user to the appropriate View Controller with that day's timetable in.

I've tried YouTube and of course here, and I can make no sense of it at all. Can someone treat me like a little baby and explain it to me. The name of the label is `DayLabel1` and I think I can connect it as an `IBOutlet`.

I make no sense out of this whatsoever, and if you can't help me, I am either
a) doomed
b) still doomed
This is not a duplicate as I'm not wanting a date picker. I'm a newb and just want a hand.

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]] weekday];
```

This code gives you to number of day in week which start from Sunday (index of Sunday is 0). You can make an String enum to get string using this index.

Here is the Swift:

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let date = NSDate()
    let dateComponent =  calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: date)
    let weekday = dateComponent.weekday
```

Comment: That's Objective-C not Swift.

Comment: WeekdayCalendarUnit is deprecated

Comment: Updated the answer, weekday property will give you index of the day of the week.

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks Sabrican - would I add it to DayLabel1 as `DayLabel1.text = String(weekday)`?